# Android databinding generates files that are not UTF-8 encoded

Tags: java, android, android-studio, character-encoding, android-databinding

I am using databinding utility. Whenever I use "_i" in the xml file, the corresponding character to it in the binding class is "\ufffd", which is capital i ("İ") in windows-1254 encoding. It is the correct capitilasation in Turkish alphabet but I don't want to use local capitalisation because it produces the following error:

```
error: illegal character: '\ufffd'
```

I have reviewed questions related to illegal char error, and most of them suggested deleting the illegal character and rewrite it. However in my case, I can not change the file, or it makes no sense to change, because it is re-generated during the rebuild.

row_program_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/program_item_linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

RowProgramItemBinding.java

```
...
@NonNull
public final LinearLayout program�temLinear;
```

Comment: `\ufffd` is the Unicode replacement character and definitely NOT anything in Windows-1254 (which is an 8-bit encoding). If you get that character at any point, then you tried to encode a character using an encoding that doesn't support that character. Show us your code.

Comment: okay thanks for the clarification. I thought it was windows-1254 encoded because when I change file encoding to windows-1254 it shows the letter "İ" which is the correct, yet not wanted, capital letter for lowercase "i".

Comment: In short, I want databinding library to name the variable as programItemLinear; not programİtemLinear or program�temLinear.

Comment: It seems I've been wrong. You seem to be running into [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141925966) which supposedly should be fixed post-3.6.

Comment: thank you, this is the exact problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joachim Sauer stated, this is a bug. For now, the solution is to change the language of javac to avoid the localization. In my case it helped to add below lines to gradle.properties.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Duser.country=TR -Duser.language=en
kotlin.compiler.execution.strategy=in-process
kotlin.daemon.jvm.options=-Duser.country=TR -Duser.language=en
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using a camelBack case in writing your view ids. 
If you look at one of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21878515/3871403).

> If you take to look at android.R.id.* fields, you will notice that all of them are in camel-case. So if the android ids are written in camel-case, I guess we have to follow this convention :)

And so you will easily avoid that error.

P.S. I too use camelCase in naming my variables
For files under /Res folder I use snake_case
Other than that I already use camelCase

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you but this is not helpful actually. Obviously this can be altered even by changing "_i" to "_I" but the key is not to change names so that it will be a convenient solution for the rest of the developers too.