# Android XML Specification Standard?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

Help me figure out what is the standard for writing xml? Which one do you use on the project?

If I use: `id = "@ + id / text_view"` and this is the correct standard as far as I know.

But if I use ViewBinding from Jetpack from Google, then my name "text_view" in the code turns into "textView"
binding.textview

I understand correctly? If I use view binding then in xml can I use Camel case when writing view names? Otherwise your eyes get confused if you use "text_view" in xml and see the result "textview" in the code ...

Comment: I would prefer to go with camel-case as android itself generate in camel-case format can be seen @ `android.R.id.*`. another question reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832290/android-id-naming-convention-lower-case-with-underscore-vs-camel-case

Comment: thx, for you help me